# changes I make in my app.css do not update pages

Tags: css, html, background-image, footer, zurb-foundation

I'm using the Zurb Foundation toolkit, it contains two stylesheets, one being the app.css which is used for editing and adding elements. The following when added to the app.css do not reflect or update on my index page. From what I've seen this should be extremely simple but it hasn't worked for me. I'm using Aptana Studio 3.

```
body {
    background-image:url('carbonfiber.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background:#333333;
    background-position:center;
}

#content {
    margin-bottom:2000px
}

#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#C00 padding-bottom: 500px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the changes to the app.scss instead

Just do the following, open the command line: (leave this screen open while you work on your project)
compass watch your-project-folder

then any changes made to your .scss will be compiled into .css

With the zurb foundation, what I do is first create another file called _main.scss (under the sass folder) and then call it from within the /sass/app.scss file using @import main; any changes made to the _main.scss are compiled into a new stylesheet called /main.css and automatically added to the app.css file.

Hope it's clear.